# What is the cow level and how do I get there?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've heard that after all of the rumors surrounding a "cow level" in the original diablo (which never actually existed), an actual cow level was put into Diablo 2.

What exactly do I have to do to reach this cow level? When I get there, what will I find?

Comment: thereisnocowlevel

Comment: You couldn't google this very much answered question? Talk about pandering.

Comment: @Sergio Actually I already knew the answer seeing as I've been there before, but it's never been asked before on here, and it's a question that seems to be asked a lot which can generate views for the site, so I asked it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's **a secret level** filled with mooing cows on par with end-game enemy difficulty. They drop unique, set, and magic items, and their King drops a rare item. It's more of a fun Easter egg than something to take advantage of.

1. Get **Wirt's Leg** on Wirt's corpse in the north while rescuing Cain from Tristam. [image: Wirt]
2. **Finish the game**, and return to Act 1 on the **same difficulty**.
3. In the Rogue Encampment, **combine** Wirt's Leg and a Town Portal Tome in the Horadric Cube. [image: inside the Cube]
4. **Enter the red portal** to Moo Moo Farm. If you want to return on the same difficulty in the future, **don't kill the Cow King**. [image: red portal]

**Video:**

Answer (score 6):

To reach the Secret Cow Level, you must first have beaten Diablo. Once you've done this return to the Rogue Encampment.

Using the Horadric Cube, obtained in Act II, you will place a Tome of Town Portal and Wirt's Leg (obtained in Tristram), before selecting Transmute.

This will open a red portal within the Rogue Encampment that will take you to the cow level.

Within, you will find **hundreds** of vicious... cows... Armed with polearms. It's an excellent place to grind experience, especially if you're playing on a server. I was able to take my paladin from 50 to 99 in only a handful of runs. It's worth noting that if you **kill** the Cow King, *you* will no longer be able to create the portal. You can, however, still enter the portal if you're playing on a server in which someone else has created said portal.

Comment: Fun fact: I'm fairly certain the cows themselves are just the devs saying "Moo." It's pretty hilarious.

Comment: Was going from lvl 50-99 in a handful of cow runs done with a mod, or did Blizzard make getting very high levels far easier than it was when the game was first released?

Comment: Handful of runs was a bit of an exaggeration. For about two weeks I did nothing but cow runs.

Comment: That's still much faster than it was initially when the race for the first lvl99 character took months of continuous play by teams who cleared the way to, and stopped just short of, killing Diablo; leaving him for the teams champion to finish off.

Answer (score 4):

The cow level can be reached by combining *Wirt's Leg* (found in old Tristram, where you rescued Cain) with a *Tome of Town Portal* (Purchasable from Akara) in the Hordric Cube.  This must be done in the Act 1 Rogue Encampment, and can be done once per difficulty.  Unless you manage to forgo killing the Cow King; in which case it can be done over and over until you do.

A portal will open up, to an area filled with cows standing upright on their hind legs.  Some will be carrying weapons as well.  This area has a much higher enemy density than most zones; be careful around the portal.  If you die nearby, you may have too many enemies to get through to retrieve your corpse.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, you must have defeated Diablo at this difficulty already.

Source: http://www.diablowiki.com/Horadric_Cube_Recipes_%28Diablo_II%29#Quest.2FOther